# How is specifically asking a question about technical terms opinion based?

Tags: discussion

So I asked a question about one option vs another, and I knew I would get people that think it is opinion based.

But I specified that I wanted answers based on technical reasoning, yet people still flag it as opinion based.

Are they right and it is not a suitable question? Or am I right, and possibly asking it in the not most efficient way?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820499/scss-which-is-better-a-mixin-or-extend-from-a-technical-point-of-view?noredirect=1#comment38532125_24820499

Comment: "Which is better" is subjective no matter how you frame the rest of your question unless you state from what perspective (speed, cpu cycles, memory consumption, et c). The point is that it will probably attract opinionated *answers*. The question might not be.

Answer (score 12):

Even if you would specify what exactly "better" means (as @JSteen says, CPU cycles? Memory consumption? Speed?), you can *still* get into a discussion about *yes, this is slightly slower, **but** that's more than offset by the gained clarity in the source code* and such things.

There very rarely is anything truly, absolutely, 100% "better" in tech. Python is *soooo* much "better" than PHP; but because I know PHP in and out I can finish a project in it in half the time... There's *always* a "but" that somebody can throw in. Even if something *is* objectively and provably "better", there are always *subjective* reasons that make it not so.

If anything, you need to ask a question which sets a clear goal which can be objectively answered, and then draw your own conclusions from it to decide for yourself which is "better".

- *Will A produce longer output than B, and does that impact C?*
- *Is doing A faster than B and why?*
- *Would A have a bigger impact on B than C?*

In this particular question you already seem to have done a lot of testing, and the only thing left for you to do is to draw a conclusion and decide on what's "better" for you. We can't make that decision for you.